# mysql: [ERROR] unknown variable 'default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'

Tags: mysql, linux, configuration

When I installed MySQL 8.0, I selected sha256 password authentication method instead of legacy, When I tried to return to native password authentication it shows an error message:
mysql: [ERROR] unknown variable 'default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'.
when I type (mysql -u root -p) command in Debian 10 Linux.

Comment: What section of the configuration file is`default-authentication-plugin` in? It looks like the mysql client is trying to read that variable. Ensure its not in a `[client]` read section of the config files.

Answer (score 3):

You need specify like this in my.cnf file :

Note: Make sure it is under `[mysqld]` section.

```
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
```

Keeping in mind only changing `default_authentication_plugin` won't allow user to login, because it will still use the old authentication plugin using which the user was create.

**To change to the plugin to need to follow below steps :**

Step1 : Instance must be enabled with the old plugin only using which the user is created. In your case the default plugin will sha256 password.

Step2 : Now re-create user with mysql_native_password plugin.

```
CREATE USER 'nativeuser'@'localhost'IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

Step3: Change my.cnf with new plugin & restart instance.

```
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
```

Answer (score 0):

**The Reason was because I frequently change password of root user, no configuration changes can solve the problem.**